# Good way to cast `dlib::matrix<T>` into `dlib::matrix<S>`?

Tags: c++, dlib

What is a good way to cast `dlib::matrix<T>` into `dlib::matrix<S>`?
For example, `dlib::matrix<float>` into `dlib::matrix<std::complex<float> >`?

Edit:
I am looking for something more efficient than this:

```
template <class T> void toComplex(const dlib::matrix<T>& matr, dlib::matrix<std::complex<T> >& res) {
  res = dlib::zeros_matrix<std::complex<T> >(matr.nr(), matr.nc());
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < matr.nr(); ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < matr.nc(); ++j) {
      res(i,j) = std::complex<T>(matr(i,j), 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit2:
Cleaner, but not much faster solution (thanks, @idclev_463035818, for suggesting):

```
template <class T> void toComplex(const dlib::matrix<T>& matr, dlib::matrix<std::complex<T> >& res) {
  res.set_size(matr.nr(), matr.nc());
  std::copy(matr.begin(), matr.end(), res.begin());
}
```

Comment: a `float` is not a `complex`, you need to convert the elements, ie copy them

Comment: It would also be good if they had the same dimensions unless you want to do something really strange.

Comment: @idclev463035818, sure, it will require copying. But copying elements one-by-one is rather slow.

Comment: @Surt, yes, I assume the dimensions are the same.

Comment: Let me ask you a question, how many bits are there in a float, how many are there in a complex?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. "but copying elements one-by-one is rather slow" but thats what you are asking for (because converting a `float` to a `complex` does require to make a copy)

Comment: @idclev463035818, I have added a baseline answer to my question. What I am asking is how to do the same thing faster / cleaner / etc.

Comment: "faster": Did you measure the code? Do you acutally have evidence that this part of the code is a bottleneck in your application? Do you really need to do this conversion? Why not store a vector of `complex` from the start? "cleaner": Your code is easy to understand. "etc": more efficient is one of the most vague terms, you need to specify what kind of efficiency you mean, there are many different sorts of efficiency: easy to write/test/debug, minimum runtime, minimum memory usage, you name it, its a trade-off, typically you can't have it all at once

Comment: @idclev463035818, Sure, let's go with "faster" then.
"Did you measure the code?": I did, and this takes significant time.
"Why not store a vector of complex from the start?": Because it does not seem that dlib::svd function can input a complex matrix. Also if it could, svd with complex matrices would probably be a new bigger bottleneck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call `complex_matrix(your_real_matrix)`.  See http://dlib.net/dlib/matrix/matrix_math_functions_abstract.h.html#complex_matrix.  There are a variety of similar casting routines.

Answer (score 1):

What a cast would at least require that

```
sizeof(float) == sizeof(std::complex<float>)
```

Which is not usually the case as the imaginary part is not placed in imaginary memory.

You might check if

```
<some code to resize res to matr without initializing anything>
std::copy(matr.cbegin(), matr.cend(), res.begin());
```

is faster.

Comment: I suppose OP is just misusing the word "cast". Question has been updated with a bit of clarification

Comment: Yep, I used "cast" word because in math sense, float is complex.

Comment: maybe worth noting that there are reasons to expect `std::copy` to be faster than copying element by element, which isnt that obvious maybe